# Problems with string replacement in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a .bat file for checking Windows & Office license in the computer. My code:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ('"wmic path SoftwareLicensingProduct where (PartialProductKey is not null) get PartialProductKey /value"') do (
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%c in ('"wmic path SoftwareLicensingProduct where (PartialProductKey='%%b') get Name /value"') do (echo Name: %%c)
echo  ^> PartialProductKey: %%b
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('"wmic path SoftwareLicensingProduct where (PartialProductKey='%%b') get LicenseStatus /value"') do (echo  ^> LicenseStatus: %%d
if %%d == "0" (echo  ^> Description: Unlicensed)
if %%d == "1" (echo  ^> Description: Licensed)
if %%d == "2" (echo  ^> Description: OOBGrace)
if %%d == "3" (echo  ^> Description: OOTGrace)
if %%d == "4" (echo  ^> Description: NonGenuineGrace)
if %%d == "5" (echo  ^> Description: Notification)
if %%d == "6" (echo  ^> Description: ExtendedGrace)
)
)
pause
```

Output: (No Description although LicenseStatus equal to "1")
[image: d]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

two small problems with your code:

1. your `if` syntax: you need to enclose both sides of the equation into quotes (or none of them)
2. `wcic` has an ugly line ending (`CRCRLF`), so the first `CR` makes it into the variable `%%d`, so it will never be equal to a pure number. `set /a` is a simple but effective method to strip that `CR`, if it's an INT32 number.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ('"wmic path SoftwareLicensingProduct where (PartialProductKey is not null) get PartialProductKey /value"') do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%c in ('"wmic path SoftwareLicensingProduct where (PartialProductKey='%%b') get Name /value"') do (echo Name: %%c)
  echo  ^> PartialProductKey: %%b
  for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('"wmic path SoftwareLicensingProduct where (PartialProductKey='%%b') get LicenseStatus /value"') do (
    set /a LicStatus=%%d
    echo  ^> LicenseStatus: !LicStatus!
    if "!LicStatus!" == "0" (echo  ^> Description: Unlicensed)
    if "!LicStatus!" == "1" (echo  ^> Description: Licensed)
    if "!LicStatus!" == "2" (echo  ^> Description: OOBGrace)
    if "!LicStatus!" == "3" (echo  ^> Description: OOTGrace)
    if "!LicStatus!" == "4" (echo  ^> Description: NonGenuineGrace)
    if "!LicStatus!" == "5" (echo  ^> Description: Notification)
    if "!LicStatus!" == "6" (echo  ^> Description: ExtendedGrace)
  )
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make this process much quicker, if you don't have multiple loops making the same WMI query:

```batch-file
@SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
@For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%G In (
'%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe Path SoftwareLicensingProduct Where^
 "PartialProductKey Is Not Null" Get LicenseStatus^,Name^,PartialProductKey^
 /Format:List 2^>NUL') Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%I In ("%%H") Do @(
    If "%%G" == "LicenseStatus" (If %%I Equ 0 Set "%%G=Unlicensed"
     If %%I Equ 1 Set "%%G=Licensed" & If %%I Equ 4 Set "%%G=NonGenuineGrace"
     If %%I Equ 2 Set "%%G=OOBGrace" & If %%I Equ 5 Set "%%G=Notification"
     If %%I Equ 3 Set "%%G=OOTGrace" & If %%I Equ 6 Set "%%G=ExtendedGrace"
    ) Else If "%%G" == "Name" (Echo %%G: %%I &SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            Echo  ^> LicenseStatus: !LicenseStatus! & EndLocal 
        ) Else Echo  ^> %%G: %%I)
@Pause
```